# Cytoscape.js 2.0 Load and Add methods

Tags: cytoscape-web, cytoscape.js

I am implementing Cytoscape.js web 2.0. I am a bit confused on the difference between load and add. I understand that in load, we do not need to specific the positions of the nodes. I used add to add a node which works when I include the position attribute, but the edges do not show even when I add the position attribute. Also, what is the difference between load and add behind the scenes? I believe that load renders the entire graph, so every time we use load, it would re render the graph. It seems that add does not do that which is good for operational costs? Is that true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`cy.load()` is used to load a new graph and run a layout on that graph.  **This is deprecated in newer versions of 2.x and it's not available in 3.x!  Run a layout after calling `cy.add()` if you want this kind of behaviour.**

`cy.add()` is used to just add elements to the existing graph.

Answer (score 0):

Putting cy.add() outside of the object right after the full object is initialized allowed adding nodes to update the graph.